# How to set labels on UITableViewsCell loaded from nib files?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have one `UITableView`, which on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` push another `UITableView` is navigation controller. Now this 2nd `UITableViewController` contans 4 section and about 1-2 rows in each section. Every Cell is loaded from nib via interface builder. Now I want to set various text labels on those cell based on the row selected in 1st `UITableview`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step by step tutorial

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Comment: Hey Madhu, The tutorial that you have suggested uses only one type of custom cell. My tableview contains  different cell.

Comment: It works the same way. It's extremely easy to modify the code presented in that tutorial to handle more than one type of cell.

Comment: @ Tom : I am using Apple documentation to build m table view. In that they put table view and all custom built tableview cell in same nib file. So should I create separate nib file for each cell and create tableview accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i did not get your question properly, what you were not able to do.

you can always set the tag for each dynamic label.

[label setTag:]

Comment: I want to initiate the UITableView which has Custom UITableViewCell.